# using sed with variables in CSH

Tags: shell, variables, awk, sed, increment

hopefully this makes sense. My ideal goal is to read a file and change a variable with another variable, but the new variable is incremented each time.

Example:

input file -

```
SAK, 123, 345
SAK, 456, 789
SAK, 789, 901
```

What I want my output to look like -

```
1, 123, 345
2, 456, 789
3, 789, 901
```

As you can see SAK is being replaced with a number, but the number is incremented every time.

I tried doing this:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
set filename=/export/home/develop/data/buy_load_file.dat

set line=1
set sak_num=1
set search=SAK

set totallines=`wc -l $filename | cut -f1 -d' '`

echo $totallines

while( $line <= $totallines )
`sed "$line s/$search/$sak_num/" $filename`
@ line++
@ sak_num++
end
```

But the sed command never works for me. I tried reading different ways to do it, but I think my issue is with $filename that it's not able to read it properly. I think awk could be another command that could possibly do what I want it to do, but not sure how.

Any ideas? Or maybe an easier way for me to get the output I desire.
Thanks!

Comment: How does C come into this? Do you plan to write a C program and compile it into an executable? That way your goal would indeed be quite easy to achieve...

Comment: oops! No I mean in c shell

Comment: Don't write C shell scripts. See https://www.google.com/search?q=csh+why+not

Answer (score 0):

If your input sample is representative in that the search string occurs exactly once in each record as the first field:

```
$ awk '{print ++n ",", $2, $3}' file
1, 123, 345
2, 456, 789
3, 789, 901
```

(**EDIT**: Replace previous versions with a single more general solution)

More generally, if the search string may occur multiple times or not at all in a given record:

```
$ cat file2
SAK, abc, def,
ghi, jkl, mno
pqr, SAK, SAK
stu, vwx, yz
aaa, bbb, SAK


$ awk -v search=SAK '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if (sub(search, n+1, $i)) ++n}1' file2
1, abc, def,
ghi, jkl, mno
pqr, 2, 3
stu, vwx, yz
aaa, bbb, 4
```

Comment: I was hoping the second example you provided would work but I keep getting this error:
cannot be longer than 3,000 bytes.

Comment: Does your input file have lines with more than 3000 bytes? If not there could be an issue of line-endings making awk interpret your entire file as a single line. If you do have long lines, perhaps you could use `gawk` which shouldn't have that line-length limit.

Comment: I will try gawk because my file is bigger than 3000 bytes

Comment: Just to be clear, the 3000 bytes is not a limit on the file size but on the size of individual lines (records) within the file.